# Differences between abstract factory pattern and factory pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Could I just said that the abstract factory pattern is just by adding a layer of abstraction above the creational patterns like factory pattern?

**Edit**: I know that for most of the cases we can use factory pattern to implement the abstract factory pattern. But I think if I use some other creational pattern, that's still, at least I will call it, a abstract factory pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract Factory is collection of the Factory Methods.

examples from real life:
[Factory Method](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/FactoryMethod/) - plasticine/mold
[Abstract Factory](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/AbstractFactory/) - cards factory

Comment: The site is amazing!